# How to switch show/hide tags

Tags: javascript

I'm not a programmer so I hope you will pardon me if I will write not correct things.

I have two fieldset with two different "id"

I tried to write a code in javascript that when I show the 1st the 2nd will be hided and viceversa.

I can't understand where I'm doing wrong. 
Can you help me?
Here html

```
<label onclick="add()"></label>
<label onclick="modify()"></label>
<fieldset id="add">some text</fieldset>
<fieldset id="modify">some other text</fieldset>
```

and here my javascript text

```
function add() {
    var x = document.getElementById('add');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function modify() {
    var y = document.getElementById('modify');
    if (y.style.display === 'none') {
        y.style.display = 'block';
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        y.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

the problem is that not only I would like that when I do click on the first it open and with another click it will close but also that when 1 fieldset is shown, the other will be hided and viceversa.

Thank you

Comment: under `modify` you are playing with style of id `x` not `y`

Comment: `x` is defined within the scope of `add` so it's `undefined` inside `modify`!

Comment: make `var x = ...;` and `var y = ...;` at the top and outside both functions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define x in your modify function. Or like @ibrahim said, just defined both variables outside the sope

```
function modify() {
    var y = document.getElementById('modify');
    var x = document.getElementById('add')
    if (y.style.display === 'none') {
        y.style.display = 'block';
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        y.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: When 'modify' is shown, onclicking on 'add', it wont be shown. x.style.display = 'block' needs to be added in else block

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function

```
function hideShow(targetId) {
    var targetNode = document.getElementById(targetId);
    if(targetNode.style.display === 'block') {
        return; // If click is on the node which is already shown, just return
    }
    var x = document.getElementById('add');
    var y = document.getElementById('modify');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
        y.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        y.style.display = 'block';
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

And use same function for both,

```
<label onclick="hideShow('add')"></label>
<label onclick="hideShow('modify')"></label>
<fieldset id="add">some text</fieldset>
<fieldset id="modify">some other text</fieldset>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, when I click the first all ok, when I click the second ok but when I click again the second, the first is still open

Comment: @S.Iandolo I have updated the answer to handle the above mentioned case. Try the updated answer once

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, if you want to get working.

```
function add() {
    var x = document.getElementById('add');
    var y = document.getElementById('modify');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
        y.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function modify() {
    var x = document.getElementById('add');
    var y = document.getElementById('modify');
    if (y.style.display === 'none') {
        y.style.display = 'block';
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        y.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

As you can see both has x and y var so that none of them is undefined. To move to clean code, you may wish to bring the var outside of the methods(reduce redundancy of the code)

Comment: Using this solution, when I click for opening and click for close the same fieldset it works but then if I click on second with the first open, the first remain opened

Comment: I added a row in both functions. after the else in both I added: in the 1st y.style.display = 'none' and in the 2nd x.style.display = 'none'

Comment: I have also added `y.style.display = 'none';` in `add()` and `x.style.display = 'none';` in `modify()`